# api.constrain for give condition if one of field is empty

Tags: python, constraints, odoo-8

I tried to use api.constrain in odoo. The case is, I want to give condition to odoo if user missing one field, odoo will give some warning like alert, and user have to give some input to the previous field. This is my code :

```
class Provinc(models.Model):
    _name = 'provinsi.model'
    _rec_name ='prov'

    prov = fields.Char(
        string='Provinsi',
    )

    res_partner_ids = fields.One2many(
        'res.partner',
        'provinsi'

    city_id  = fields.One2many(
        'city.model',
        'provinsi_id'
    )

class city(models.Model):
    _name = 'kota.model'
    _rec_name ='city'

    city = fields.Char(
        string='City',
    )
    res_partner_city = fields.One2many(
        'res.partner',
        'city'
    )

    provinsi_id = fields.Many2one(
        'provinsi.model',
        string='provinsi',
    )


class Master_data(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    provinsi = fields.Many2one(
        'provinsi.model',
        'provinsi',
    )

    city = fields.Many2one(
        'city.model',
        'city',
    )

    @api.onchange('provinsi')
    def show_provinsi(self):
        return {'domain': {'city': [('provinsi_id', '=', self.provinsi.id)]}}


    @api.constrains('provinsi')
    @api.onchange('city')    
    def show_kota(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.provinsi == False:
                raise ValidationError("is gonna be error")
```

I have tried 2 ways. First, I put the api.constrain insode class City, and it's doesn't work,second ways I tried put the api.constrain like the code inside class master, and the result remains the same.

Comment: make your all field necessary and use try block and in exception raise your error and invoke your code again through function call in except block

Answer (score 0):

you only need onchang not any constrains to display warning!

```
@api.onchange('city')    
def show_kota(self):
    if self.city and not self.provinsi:
        raise ValidationError("is gonna be error")
```

now if you select value in city field and provinsi missing value then it will display error msg

> guessing field "city" and "provinsi" is in 'res.partner' form view!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a field value is empty or not, just use `required ="1"` like:

```
<field name="provinsi" required="1"/>
```